# What is the full syntax for calling a stored procedure in SubSonic 3.0?

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic3

What is the full syntax for a stored procedure using SubSonic 3.0? Here is my code which is not working:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
StoredProcedure sp = test.Usersp_Stock_Search("", 0, "");
sp.ExecuteDataSet();
```

Answer (score 0):

ds=sp.ExecuteDataSet()